# rake aborted! cannot load such file -- mysql/mysql_api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on Fedora19.

```
[root@localhost coffee]# ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-linux]
[root@localhost coffee]# rails -v
Rails 3.0.
```

This is my Gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.9'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'


gem 'mysql'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger (ruby-debug for Ruby 1.8.7+, ruby-debug19 for Ruby 1.9.2+)
# gem 'ruby-debug'
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

# Bundle the extra gems:
# gem 'bj'
# gem 'nokogiri'
# gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
# gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'

# Bundle gems for the local environment. Make sure to
# put test-only gems in this group so their generators 
# and rake tasks are available in development mode:
# group :development, :test do
#   gem 'webrat'
# end
```

When i do rake db:migrate, I got this error

```
[root@localhost coffee]# rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- mysql/mysql_api
/home/charul/coffee/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/charul/coffee/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

mysql is installed in my system.

```
[root@localhost coffee]# service mysqld restart
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart  mysqld.service
```

This is my database.yml file.

```
development:
    adapter:  mysql
    encoding: utf8
    database: ajax
    username: root
    password: root123
    host: 127.0.0.1
    port: 3306
```

Also, bundle install command worked perfectly.

```
[root@localhost coffee]# bundle install
Using rake (10.1.1) 
Using abstract (1.0.0) 
Using activesupport (3.0.9) 
Using builder (2.1.2) 
Using i18n (0.5.3) 
Using activemodel (3.0.9) 
Using erubis (2.6.6) 
Using rack (1.2.8) 
Using rack-mount (0.6.14) 
Using rack-test (0.5.7) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.38) 
Using actionpack (3.0.9) 
Using mime-types (1.25.1) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.15) 
Using mail (2.2.20) 
Using actionmailer (3.0.9) 
Using arel (2.0.10) 
Using activerecord (3.0.9) 
Using activeresource (3.0.9) 
Using json (1.8.1) 
Using mysql (2.9.1) 
Using bundler (1.3.5) 
Using rdoc (3.12.2) 
Using thor (0.14.6) 
Using railties (3.0.9) 
Using rails (3.0.9) 
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Can anyone help how to solve this..thanks

Comment: try `gem 'mysql2'` and mysql installed in your system..?

Comment: No, it didn't worked. Still got the same error

Comment: what does your yml file look like?

Comment: in terminal, `mysqladmin -u root -p ping` you should get a msg `mysqld is alive` so clears me you have installed mysql in your s/m.

Comment: [root@localhost coffee]# mysqladmin -u root -p ping
Enter password: 
mysqld is alive
@Nitin mysql is installed.

Comment: @charul no idea.. found the soln?

Answer (score 1):

You should use mysql2 instead of mysql gem. Just do:

`gem install mysql2`

change your database adapter in your database.yml file

```
development:
   adapter: mysql
```

to

```
development:
   adapter: mysql2
```

And change your Gemfile:

```
#gem 'mysql'
gem 'mysql2'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql --version '2.8.1' -- --with-mysql-   config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.15/bin/mysql_config
```